# php cannot use API data

Tags: php, json, api

I send a request and get back JSON, so I convert that JSON to an array, but I cannot use the array with my php:

```
$all_transactions_raw = file_get_contents("xxx");

$all_transactions = json_decode( $all_transactions_raw );

 foreach ( $all_transaction as $transaction ) {
    echo $transaction;
  }
```

First part of the very long output:

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [transactions] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [id] => t1rtn-gsjkadfv 
                [date] => 2017-11-01 
                [amount] => -8847
                [memo] => 
                [cleared] => reconciled 
                [approved] => 1 
                [flag_color] =>
```

why does the above code not print a list of transactions given by the api request?

when I use `print_r( $all_transactions );` I can print out a long string of what looks like an array but I cannot access the data contained in it as separate chunks.  Am I missing something?

Comment: show us your expected json result that you want to work with.

Comment: `$transaction` is also probably an array, so try `print_r($transaction);` in the loop as `echo` will probably fail.

Comment: You should also add `true` as the second argument to [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to assure that you get the result as associative arrays instead of object. However, since we have no idea what the result looks like, I can't know if that's the issue or not. Please share the value of `$all_transactions_raw`.

Comment: @ttrasn I want to work with the result as an array so that I can say `$all_transactions[1]` and do something with that.

Comment: @NigelRen so that did work, BUT I can only print_r if I do the entire array (I cannot break out of the loop)  How can I convert the json into a usable array?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Unfortunately that does not seem to make a difference here but the sample output is above.  The response is very long so I just did the beginning.

Comment: Something's strange here. If you're using `json_decode()` without `true` as a second argument like in your code, I don't see how the result could be associative arrays instead of objects? What exactly is that array a dump of? The raw value or inside the loop?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did use true in the decode statement and with that one of the answrs below solved it, I had to structure the array reference differently, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are missing these keys in foreach

```
$all_transactions_raw = file_get_contents("xxx");

$all_transactions = json_decode( $all_transactions_raw );

 foreach ( $all_transaction['data']['transactions'] as $transaction ) {
    echo $transaction;
  }
```

Comment: yes! that did it, I can work with single transactions now using that, thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm failing to see how this would work at all? How can `$all_transactions` possibly be an associative array with the above code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson idk but I am able to do `  print_r( $all_transactions['data']['transactions'][0] );
` which prints out an array of all data associated with the 0th transaction in the output

Comment: if you have online one array then you can do like `$all_transactions['data']['transactions'][0]` otherwise you should need loop

Comment: @fall3n - Yes, but as you said in your comment, you are actually using `true` as the second argument. This answer doesn't so it's actually wrong and could cause confusion for future visitors seeing it and trying it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh yes, my mistake, I combined the two answers